# Corona sdk : Play sound when main object hits an obstacle

Tags: audio, coronasdk, playsound

I want to play a specific sound when a ball hits a specific object (transparent obstacle) or passes through a specific area.

```
    function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then 
    storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400)


    end`
    end


`ball = display.newImage("ball.png") --main object code
ball.x = 100; ball.y = 100
physics.addBody(ball, "dynamic", {density=.05, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(ball)`


--Obstacles code




`obst1 = display.newImage("obst1.png")
obst1.x = 640; obst1.y = -500
obst1.speed = 2
physics.addBody(obst1, "static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.3, density=.1 })
screenGroup:insert(obst1)`

`missile1 = display.newImage("missile.png")
missile1.x = 700; missile1.y = math.random(5,1090)
missile1.speed = math.random(2,6)
missile1.initY = missile1.y
missile1.amp = math.random(20,100)
physics.addBody(missile1, "static", {density=0.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(missile1)
missile1.angle = math.random(20,100)`
```

So how can I make the ball collide with another object and start a sound without stopping the game ( on the collision function, the minute the object collides it goes to the restart screen)

Thank you so much ...

Comment: What did you already try ?

Comment: @Zulu I've eddited my question just to make clearer . Sorry for that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you seem so new to Corona I try to you just give you some advise and guides:

first of all you should know how to detect collisions: [Physics Body](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/physicsBodies/index.html#create)
after that you should know how to handle Collision Events: [Collision](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/collision/index.html) and [Collision Detection](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html)
and then you should know how to play sounds: [Sound Play](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/play.html)

here is an example in a game I coded mySelf:

```
--implement the physics for the project
local physics = require "physics";
physics.start()

...

-- stones pics
stone1 = stons_shape[stoneNumber][2]
stone2 = stons_shape[stoneNumber][2]
stone3 = stons_shape[stoneNumber][2]
-- stones physics
physics.addBody (stone1,"Dynamic", stons_shape[stoneNumber][1]:get(stons_shape[stoneNumber][0]))
physics.addBody (stone2,"Dynamic", stons_shape[stoneNumber][1]:get(stons_shape[stoneNumber][0]))
physics.addBody (stone3,"Dynamic", stons_shape[stoneNumber][1]:get(stons_shape[stoneNumber][0]))

-- stones property
stone1.linearDamping = stons_shape[stoneNumber][5] * 0.03
stone1.angularDamping= 1.5
stone1.power = stons_shape[stoneNumber][3]


function onCollision (event)

    if(event.object2.myName=="stone1")or(event.object2.myName=="stone2")or(event.object2.myName=="stone3") then
        -- here one stone touches another and 
        -- and so you can play a sound 
    end
end
--"onCollision" event is for all objects having collision on each other
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision)
```

Comment: I've eddited my question to make it clearer, So based on what you wrote should I use your onCllision  function if(event.ball.myName=="obst1")or(event.ball.myName=="obst2")or(event.ball.myName=="obst3") then add the play sound code , close the function then say else  if event.phase == "began" then 
    storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400) end  ? Sorry for my poor knowledge :(

Comment: nearly Yeah, use if(event.object1.myName == "obts1" or ...).
No problem bro. we all passed have been through it ;)

Comment: Ouuuf, ok it wasn't working because I havn't the     obst1.myName = "obst1"  wrote in the create scene, It seems like for each obst I added I have to ref its name in the createScene .... thank you a lot , 
 You really helped me a lot ... now I can add an else then say if the ball hits the wall it goes directly to the restart . It's gonna be if(event.object1.myName == "obs1") then play sound else (event.object1.myName=="wall") then storyboard.gotoScene (gameover) end ? is it ok ? or I have to put object2 instead of object1

Comment: all done function onCollision (event)

    if (event.object1.myName == "obst1") or (event.object1.myName == "obst2") then 
    audio.play(my_sound)
    end
 
    if (event.object1.myName == "obst3") then 
    storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400)

    end
end -----> thank's to you my friend .... ( I hope that when I loadSound on my game.lua it will be played :D )